# Region Co-ordinates List Not Resetting

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, deep-learning, computer-vision

Here, I am trying to select regions of interest manually and give labels to them. For that purpose, I used Tkinter, however, when I draw the rectangular box, it is not shown and is visible only after I enter information into the dialog boxes from simpledialog.

The next issue is that even when I press the key 'r', the information stored in points is still there stored. It changes into an empty list due to the .clear() method but in the final print, the coordinates of the region of interest selected before pressing 'r' is still there in new_points.

Where did I go wrong? Can't figure it out.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter
import tkinter.simpledialog

#store rectangular points and define whether that specific region of interest is to cropped
rect = []
cropping = False

def click_crop(event,x,y,flag,params):
    global rect,cropping
    

    #if the left mouse if clicked,start recording the position of 
    #x and y co-ordinates
    
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        rect = [(x,y)]
        cropping = True
        
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        
        rect.append((x,y))
        

        cropping = False
        
        cv2.rectangle(image,rect[0],rect[1],(255,0,0),2)
        
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        dtype = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Data Type","Text/Box..")
        root.withdraw()
        
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        info_type = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Info Type","Name/Country/Email/Phone..")
        root.withdraw()
        
        rect.append(dtype)
        rect.append(info_type)
        #print(rect)
        
        
        #cv2.imshow('Image',image)
image = cv2.imread("path_to_image")
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow('Image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Image',click_crop)

points = []

while True:
    cv2.imshow('Image',image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        
    if key==ord('c'):
        #Break from the loop
        break
    elif len(rect)==4&key!='r':
        points.append([(rect[0][0],rect[0][1],rect[1][0],rect[1][1]),rect[2],rect[3]])
#         points.append([rect[0][0],rect[0][1],rect[1][0],rect[1][1]])
        #print(points)
    
    elif key==ord('r'):
        image = clone.copy()
        temp = points.clear()
        print(points)#I want to reset the entire list when r is pressed which is not happening
        #Here we resetted all the regions of interest that we captured
        
print(points)
new_points = []
for coords in points:
    if coords not in new_points:
        new_points.append(coords)
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Should `len(rect)==4&key!='r'` be `len(rect)==4 and key!='r'` instead?  Also I think that you need to clear `rect` after it is appended to `points`, otherwise you will never get to the last `elif`.

Comment: yeah..adding rect.clear() and points.clear() did the job here. Now, question remains why the bounding rectangle is not being shown when the tkinter dialog box is active

Comment: tkinter dialog is a modal dialog so it will block the main application.

Comment: anyway to overcome it

Comment: Call `cv2.imshow('Image', image)` before opening the dialogs.  Also you don't need to create two instances of `Tk`, just one is enough and it is better to call `root.destroy()` after the two dialogs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind support. Really helped sort out the issue.